# C++ fieldtype Datetime2 instead of Datetime

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, mfc

We updated our SQL Server database from 2012 to 2016 recently.

Now, our very old C++ programs run into an issue. Very old means, there is no one left who can maintain the code anymore.

The problem is: In the code itself, the Date Fields are initialized as

```
RFX_Date(pFX, _T("[CREATION_DATE_CENTRAL]"), m_CREATION_DATE_CENTRAL);
```

The query, which is executed onto the database looks like this:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql   
      N'SELECT * FROM ADDON_Table      
      WHERE NR = @number 
      and CREATION_DATE_LOCAL = @date1
      and CREATION_DATE_CENTRAL = @date2',  
      N'@number int, @date1 datetime2, @date2 datetime2',  
      9817434, '2019-11-19 10:03:22.000', '2019-11-24 19:24:38.5270000';
```

At least one row should be returned. But the query returns no row.

I figured out, that after changing the datatype of `date2` from `datetime2` to `datetime` returns a row.

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql   
      N'SELECT * FROM ADDON_Table   
      WHERE NR = @number 
      and CREATION_DATE_LOCAL = @date1
      and CREATION_DATE_CENTRAL = @date2',  
      N'@number int, @date1 datetime2, @date2 datetime',  
      9817434, '2019-11-19 10:03:22.000', '2019-11-24 19:24:38.527';
```

My conclusion is, that somethings happened after updating the DB to 2016 with the `datetime`/`datetime2` implementation.

Don't know if our Application/ODBC uses from now on `datetime2` instead of `datetime`. Or is there a new behavior of the `sp_executesql`.

It would be great if someone can help me.

Comment: You should check the datatypes inside your tables. Because your query requires an exact match on both date columns (as well as a matching id/nr). Which for dates of this order, means you can easily miss expected records. What are the datatypes inside the table? Do you get hits if you run the query with >= instead of a =. What are the results?

Comment: Add the relevant schema for the `ADDON_Table` to your question if you can. The datetime2 columns could have a different precision than you expect, e.g.: `datetime2(3)`.

Comment: The both fields at the table are from type 'datetime'

Comment: Even If I run the query with >=, there are no hits. But if I use <=, then I got one hit.